# Why is my table duplicated with the same data

Tags: php, pdo

I have tried all I can but no head-way.
I was trying to fetch data from the databasse but it will only end up duplicating the same information from the db 8 times.

```
<?php 
  $useremail=$_SESSION['login'];  
  $sql = "SELECT * from zhinvest where userEmail=:useremail";
    $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query -> bindParam(':useremail',$useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
 $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=$query->rowCount();
         if($query->rowCount() > 0)
         {
            foreach($results as $result)
         { 
?>
```

Somebody should help me, I can't figue out where I am not getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

if field `useremail` isn't unique then information can repeat

You can use `LIMIT` in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from zhinvest where userEmail=:useremail LIMIT 1";
```